# Different time for direct ajax call and XHR

Tags: php, ajax, profiling, pagespeed

I am displaying many data tables on my dashboard and load the data over AJAX. In my chrome dev network view I see, that my calls are all over 5 seconds. An example here of > 11 seconds

[image]

But when I call the request direct in Chrome I have as time 700 ms

[image]

How is this possible? What could be the problem?

Comment: Is it possible that the direct request doesn't have the same data?

Comment: They are exactly the same. I am using Symfony and open the request directly from the dev toolbar

Comment: not enough info to offer a fix but have you considered the possibility that the problem is the numerous requests are overloading the server (maybe a misbehaving script / query on the DB?) When you run one request from console it may not hit your server with the same load as the multiple requests you are making at once.